# String and number in Angular misunderstood

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Entity:

```
export class Item {
  name: string;
  value: number;
}
```

And mock-class:

```
export const ITEMS: Item[] = [
  {
    name: 'Локальный сервер',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Удаленный сервер',
    value: 2
  }
];
```

In my template:

```
<li class="list-group-item"  *ngFor="let item of itemsList">
                  <input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="radioSelected" name="list_name" value="{{item.value}}" (change)="onItemChange(item)"/> {{item.name}}
                </li>
```

And in my controller:

```
onItemChange(item) {
    this.getSelecteditem();
  }

  getSelecteditem() {
    this.radioSel = ITEMS.find(Item => Item.value === parseInt(this.radioSelected.toString(), 10));
  }
```

I dont like this part:  *parseInt(this.radioSelected.toString()*, but just a **this.radioSelected** without *parseInt* and *.toString* doesnt work. Why? I want to pass and get just a number, not a string! How can I do it?

Comment: did you try to declare radioSelected as number?

Comment: You can make use of  == and remove parseInt

Comment: can you create a demo at stackblitz ideally it should work

Comment: 1) radioSelected is a number!
2)  == - is work! But i have a varning from Tslint, that "==" must be a "===".

Answer (score 3):

Could you try to pass in down the value of the item selected:

```
onItemChange(item: ITEM) {
   this.getSelecteditem(item); // pass in the item here
}
```

And then find the item based on that item's value:

```
getSelecteditem(item: ITEM) {
    this.radioSel = ITEMS.find(Item => Item.value === item.value); // compare against the param passed in
}
```

I would also recommend you to use the typings as I've done, will be much easier and fun :)

Comment: Sorry, it doesnt work: "cannot find name ITEMS"   (((